# Volume Button does not work during Recovery Mode

Tags: recovery-mode, samsung-galaxy-ace

Hello I am trying to update my samsung Ace into 4.1 and for this reason I need to run Recovery Mode. I am able to open Recovery Mode but I cannot move using my Volume Button. Is there a way to solve this issue? Thanks in advance